# How to describe a python script with comments?

Tags: python

I have a Python script that can be run completely standalone. I somehow want to create a general description of what the script does in a comment.

What is the Pythonic way of doing so? Is it just like my example below? Somehow it feels wrong to have it before the imports, but I'm not sure?

As an example I have:

```
"""
This is the example description
"""

import argparse
from datetime import datetime
import re
import sys
from xml.etree import ElementTree


def some functions():
    x = x+1
```

Comment: That is the pythonic way.

Comment: I'd use a hashtag (`#`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
"""
Here you can add the copyright contents
This is the overall description of this script 
And the available classes/functions in this script
You can also add usage
"""

import argparse
from datetime import datetime
import re
import sys
from xml.etree import ElementTree


def some functions():
    """
    This is function related description what is this function and how it works
    You can also add expected input and output information
    """
    x = x+1 #adding 1 in the input
    # comment for the below complicated logic
    # Explain the below logic
    x = x*x*1*2*x
```

You can see this [page](https://realpython.com/python-comments-guide/) for more comments practices.

Answer (score 1):

This is what [PEP 257 - Docstring Conventions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) has to say about it:

> The docstring of a script (a stand-alone program) should be usable as
>   its "usage" message, printed when the script is invoked with incorrect
>   or missing arguments (or perhaps with a "-h" option, for "help"). Such
>   a docstring should document the script's function and command line
>   syntax, environment variables, and files. Usage messages can be fairly
>   elaborate (several screens full) and should be sufficient for a new
>   user to use the command properly, as well as a complete quick
>   reference to all options and arguments for the sophisticated user.

Answer (score 1):

First thing: note that triple-quoted strings are NOT "comments", they are real Python strings. It happens that they are also commonly used for **docstrings** (a docstring is a string just at the start of a module, class or function that is used by Python as the "help" string for this module / class / function) since you often need more than one line here but just any string would do.

Comments are, of course, lines starting with a `#`, and are just totally ignored by python.

Now you say:

> I somehow want to create a general description of what the script does in a comment.

If what you want is really a comment, use the comment syntax. If what you want is something that can be used by Python for documentation (like ie `import yourmodule; help(yourmodule);`, then use a docstring.

Answer (score 0):

Use this template:

```
"""
Author: YOU
"""

import argparse
from datetime import datetime
import re
import sys
from xml.etree import ElementTree


def some functions():
    """
    This is a description .....
    """
    x = x+1 #adding 1 in the input (this is a comment)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use a hashtag (`#`). Lines starting with a hashtag are not read as code.